# Не работает бот написанный на python с помощью библиотеки TeleBot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот, telebot

я написал прстейшего бота с помощью библиотеки Telebot, но есть загвоздка, когда запускаю его через терминал(linux) ошибок не находит, но когда пишу боту он не реагирует

Вот код:

```
import config
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(*тут токен в одинарных кавычках*)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def welcome(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "hello world!")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def lalala(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: вы можете добавить print(bot.get_me()) перед bot = чтобы увидеть запустился ли бот

Comment: Сделал все как вы написали, консоль выводит это: <telebot.types.User instance at 0xb7c30ecc>

Comment: прошу прощения, print(bot.get_me()) должен быть после объекта bot. иначе будет ошибка name 'bot' is not defined. уточните еще, вы используете виртуальное окружение на Linux? библиотека установлена конечно же? файл исполняемый (chmod +x %name_file.py%)?

Answer (score -1):

Судя по коду строка import config лишняя. Если у Вас нет в проекте файла config.py, то код не запустится. 
Данный код будет работать без данной строки. 
Код:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(*тут токен в одинарных кавычках*)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
  def welcome(message):
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "hello world!")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
  def lalala(message):
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Скорее всего у него токен в конфиге